# Unable to delete project (lock) even though I removed Dialogflow Agent

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Unable to remove GCP project because locked by DialogFlow Agent used.

Even though I removed DialogFlow Agent, it stills unable to remove the project and I found  a command line solution but it is not working.

```
$gcloud config set project <project_id>
$gcloud alpha resource-manager liens list --project <project_id>
$gcloud alpha resource-manager liens delete p218xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx--xxxxxf37294
```

ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.resource-manager.liens.delete) HTTPError 404:

Can you please advise me?

Thanks,
Warawich

Answer (score 0):

Update, I able to remove the project by steps below:

Cause: I try to followup  https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/support/troubleshooting?agent=any&category=any#gcloud_1 and run gCloud command line on GCP cloud shell but not working.

Solution:

- Install/Update components gcloud cli on your computer.

[Update gcloud cli](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9cpQ.png)

- Follow up https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/support/troubleshooting?agent=any&category=any#gcloud_1 again.

Thank you,
Warawich